# UIView highlighted background gradient

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer

I am trying to use a gradient as a background to my UIView.

```
    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [[CAGradientLayer alloc] init];
    gradientLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, self.currencyView.frame.size.width, self.currencyView.frame.size.height);
    [gradientLayer setLocations:@[@0.f, @1.f]];
    [gradientLayer setColors:@[(id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor,(id)[UIColor blackColor].CGColor]];
    [self.animalView.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];
```

I have made this view tappable by adding a **UITapGestureRecognizer**

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showAnimalDetails)];
    [self.currencyView addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
```

My question is, how can I add a **highlighted gradient** (possibly just reversing the gradient) when the touch was detected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: change alpha for some second when your view is Tapped and set alpha as it is .. :) might be helpful in your case. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make that layer a class variable instead of local, then inside your `showAnimalDetails` function change the gradient properties however you wish.  Then call `setNeedsDisplay`.  You are going to have to deal with deselection by other means though.

Comment: @Neelesh Instead of modifying the colors, try removing it from the self.layers, then recreate a new gradientLayer and re add it to your self.layers.